# How to connect one monitor at two different networks?

Tags: internet

I have two networks and for each one I use a PC. These network should remain separate because one is an internal network that must be protected and another is the Internet. How can I access these networks with only one PC and to be sure that my intranet is fully protected from the Internet threats ?

Comment: One PC connected to a secure and an unsecured network is a **_huge_** security risk.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to access both networks directly at the same time.

In a professional environment you would use VLANS, which gives you the ability to access multiple networks directly from a single network card and thus system.

The cheap/SOHO option would be to use two network cards.

In both cases you would place very strict rules on the configuration of said system:

```
1) No routing/(P)NATing/VPN/tunnels or other funny stuff
2) A correctly configured firewall
3) An up to date OS with a strict updating policy
```

Answer (score 0):

accessing your 2 networks with only one PC it ok, but if you want to fully Protect your intranet, I suggest to use a KVM, this will give you the impression of using a single monitor.